# Storing an unknown function from another class to execute later on itself

Tags: c#

I have a class that parameters there can change, i'm creating a class that sorts groups of the first class, by the given parameter it needed to be sorted by.

```
class class1
{
   private int p1; 
   private int p2;
 //and etc depending on the need of it
}
```

for each parameter there is a get function.

i tried to do the following:

```
class class2<T>
{
   private Func<T> getValue;
   public class2(Func<T> getValue)
   {
       this.getValue = getValue; 
   }

 public void Add(class1 cs)
 {
     //here is where i want to execute getValue on cs itself to compare them to one another. 
 }
}
```

I have tried doing the following in the main class:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            class1 c1 = new class1(1, 2);
            class2<int> c2 = new class2<int>(c1.getp1)
        }
    }
```

but it only stores the the function for c1, and i cant execute it as i need it.

Is there a way to do it? 
Thanks ahead for the help and sorry for the dumb explanation.

Comment: It's a little unclear. In `Add`, can you just call `cs.getp1()` instead of using a `Func` passed into the constructor?

Comment: i dont know if he will want p1, p2 or something else, so when class2 is created i want to get the "get" function of the property that the Add is going to be sorting by.

Comment: Very unclear. "on cs itself" , but cs == c1 so the problem seems solved.

Comment: Also, check for typos, especially in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Func<T>`, use `Func<class1,T>` ([msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
class class2<T>
{
   private Func<class1, T> getValue;
   public class2(Func<class1, T> getValue)
   {
       this.getValue = getValue;
   }

   public void Add(class1 cs)
   {
       // Something like this
       var val = this.getValue(class1);
       // do something with val
   }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        class1 c1 = new class1(1, 2);
        // create the Func as a lambda and pass to the constructor.
        class2<int> c2 = new class2<int>(c => c.getp1)
    }
}
```

I haven't ran/compiled this.

Comment: Thank you! this is what i meant to do!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think what you want is this:

```
class class1
    {
        private int _p1;
        private int _p2;
        //and etc depending on the need of it

        public class1(int p1, int p2)
        {
            _p1 = p1;
            _p2 = p2;
        }

        public int getp1()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class class2<T>
    {
        private Func<T> getValue;

        public class2(Func<T> getValue)
        {
            this.getValue = getValue;
        }

        public void Add(class1 cs)
        {
            //here is where i want to execute getValue on cs itself to compare them to one another. 
            getValue();
        }
    }

class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            class1 c1 = new class1(1, 2);
            Func<int> getp1 = c1.getp1;
            class2<int> c2 = new class2<int>(getp1);
            c2.Add(c1);
        }
    }
```